# Conda installation on windows

Tags: python, conda, pythonpath

I have done the following:
I installed anaconda on my Windows machine. Afterwards, I manually added the following paths to my PATH variable: `C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3`, `C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3\scripts` and `C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3\Library\bin`.

I guess my question is now somewhat two-fold:

1. When now opening a terminal and invoking python, why does the sys.path include the following:

   > C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3\python37.zip 
   >   C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3\DLLs
   >   C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3\lib 
   >   C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3 
   >   C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages 
   >   C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32
   >   C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
   >   C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin

What is the process behind this?

2. When I now create a new environment using conda, I can actually import modules installed in my base environment, which however are not listed as installed in the new environment. I suppose this is because they are in my sys.path. Will this cause conflicts when installing a different version of a package in my new environment? In essence: is this the correct setup of my anaconda installation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

About the first question, this is happening because you installed python using anacoda so the path to python's interpreter is through the directory of where conda is installed. You can check your environment variables [check this](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

But this will not cause you any problem.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. Yes, I guess the python interpreter is found within the anaconda installation, since I added C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3 to PATH. But why does sys.path then contain C:\path_to_conda\anaconda3\DLLs for example?